# Babel-loader not transpiling JSX component. ModuleParseError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, babel-loader

I'm trying to build a standalone component as a package. I'm using webpack to transpile all the CSS and JS/JSX files into JS. I'm able to build the package and pack it into a `.tgz` file using `npm pack`. However, when I install the package in another project and try using the component from the installed package. I'm getting this error:

> ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (34:8)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

And, in the terminal of the running project, I get this:

> error - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    mode:'production',
    entry:'./src/components/StandaloneComponent.js',
    output:{
        path:path.join(__dirname,'dist'),
        filename:'StandaloneComponent.js',
        libraryTarget:"commonjs2"
    },
    module:{

        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.js|jsx$/,
                exclude:/(node_modules)/,
                use:'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                use:[
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve:{
        alias:{
            'react':path.resolve(__dirname,'./node_modules/react'),
            'react-dom':path.resolve(__dirname,'./node_modules/react-dom'),
            'next':path.resolve(__dirname,'./node_modules/next')
        }
    },

    externals:{
        react:{
            commonjs:"react",
            commonjs2:"react",
            amd:"React",
            root:"React"
        },
        "react-dom":{
            commonjs:"react-dom",
            commonjs2:"react-dom",
            amd:"ReactDOM",
            root:"ReactDOM"
        },
        next:{
            commonjs:"next",
            commonjs2:"next",
            amd:"Next",
            root:"Next"
        }
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "testcomponent",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "description": "A lightweight and easy to use package.",
  "main": "./src/components/StandaloneComponent.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "NextJS",
    "react"
  ],
  "peerDependencies": {
    "next": "^12.0.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-stage-0": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "next": "^12.0.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.64.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

I further installed this package in another project like this:

```
npm install path/to/tgz/testcomponent-1.0.3.tgz
```

And then imported the component as:

```
import StandaloneComponent from 'testcomponent'
```

As a possible workaround, I tried changing the extension of the component file from `.js` to `.jsx` and rebuilt the `.tgz`, but got the same result.
Looking at the error, I feel that `babel-loader` is unable to convert JSX into JS, which further is causing the import error, but I'm not entirely sure about it.
What could be causing this error?
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: I see that you are excluding your `node_modules` folder.  You need to include the package

Answer (score 0):

The regex rule that you are using to load the JS and JSX file i.e. `test:/\.js|jsx$/` seems incorrect in this case. You can fix it in following two ways:

1. Using capture groups: So when using or you need to capture the both the character sets as `/\.(js|jsx)$/`. This will consider both js and jsx extension. The earlier version just doesnt match the regex properly because of missing character set.
2. Using `?` occurrence: You can also modify your regex to use the `x` as an zero or one occurrence using `?` matcher. So the other option will be `/\.jsx?$/`

Comment: Hello.  I did try updating the regex format as suggested. It is still throwing the same error.

Comment: Did you build the project ?

Comment: Yes, after updating the regex, I did `npm run build` followed by `npm pack`

Comment: Which format did you use ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Could you please care to explain what do you mean by which format?

Comment: Do you mean the format of the exported package? It is in tarball format.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to include the package you installed under `include` otherwise it looks like Webpack is configured to ignore your `node_modules` folder:

```
exclude: /(node_modules)/,
```

So make sure to let Webpack know what folders in `node_modules` that you do want to compile

```
include: [
  path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/testcomponent'
]
```